# Async/Await and Then not working in my case

Tags: node.js

I have a function which contains a thousand of objects in an array:

```
function Alltransaction(transactionArray) {
    transactionArray.map(async (transaction) => {
        dataAgainsthash = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction)

        TransactionObject = {
            transactionHash : transaction,
            from : dataAgainsthash.from
        };

        transactionArray.push(TransactionObject)
        console.log("transaction array", transactionArray)
    });
}
```

then i have another function which stores these thousands of object array into db

```
function saveTransactionToDb() {
    console.log("after loop",transactionArray)
    transactionss = new Transaction({
        blockNumber : blockNumbers ,
        transactions : transactionArray
    })

    // Now save the transaction to database
    await transactionss.save();
    // console.log("save to database")
}
```

then I call this in my router

```
await Alltransaction(transactionArray);
await saveTransactionToDb();
```

and I also try

```
Alltransaction(transactionArray).then(saveTransactionToDb())
```

But it always runs `saveTransactionToDb()` before the array of object populates the `Alltransaction()` method

Comment: it print (after loop, []) which i console in saveTransactionToDb() first .then it print (transactionArray,contain All object) which i console in the Alltransaction() method.

Comment: Please, format the code, it's unreadable.

Comment: please clean your answer a bit

Comment: Refer to the docs about `Array#map`, you're not using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

have you try the **async** keyword before saveTransactionToDb and Alltransaction functions??

```
async function Alltransaction(transactionArray){
     // your code       
}
```

`async function saveTransactionToDb(){
        // your code logic*
        await transactionss.save();
 }`

Comment: what I feel is that both the functions that you used without async keywords

Comment: No, i add async keyword this is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

First, in `Alltransaction` the promise must be returned as well. In your code the function starts some processes but doesn't not await on it. Also, do not push the promises to the original array. I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish there. Because mapping over the array gives you an array of promises, you can unify all of them with `Promise.all()`.

```
function Alltransaction(transactionArray) {
    const promises = transactionArray.map(async (transaction) => {
        dataAgainsthash = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction)

        const TransactionObject = {
            transactionHash : transaction,
            from : dataAgainsthash.from
        };

        return TransactionObject;
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Change `saveTransactionToDb` to receive an array instead of using the original array.

Then you'll be able to call it as:

```
const t = await Alltransaction(transactionArray);
await saveTransactionToDb(t);
```

Your second try it's not correct:

```
Alltransaction(transactionArray).then(saveTransactionToDb())
```

It's the same as:

```
const t = Alltransaction(transactionArray);
const s = saveTransactionToDb();
t.then(s)
```

That's why `saveTransactionToDb` doesn't way for transactions to complete. To use then, just pass the function without calling it:

```
Alltransaction(transactionArray).then(saveTransactionToDb)
```